# Can't send reply with markup by Telegram Bot API

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Trying to build up a simple bot.
Here's my code:

```
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Telegram\Bot\Api;
    $telegram = new Api('<MY TOKEN>');
    $result = $telegram -> getWebhookUpdates();

    $text = $result["message"]["text"]; 
    $chat_id = $result["message"]["chat"]["id"]; 
    $name = $result["message"]["from"]["username"]; 
    $keyboard = [["news"],["more news"],["loolz"]]; 


    if ($text == "/start") {
            $reply = "Hello there!";
            $reply_markup = $telegram->replyKeyboardMarkup([ 'keyboard' => $keyboard, 'resize_keyboard' => true, 'one_time_keyboard' => false ]);
            $telegram->sendMessage([ 'chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $reply, 'reply_markup' => $reply_markup ]);
    }

    if ($text == "/btn1") {
        $reply = "AWESOME! YOU TAPPED 2nd BUTTON :)";

        $telegram->sendMessage([ 'chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $reply ]);
    }
```

Condition `if ($text == "/btn1")` works, but it stops when i add `$reply_markup` to  "btn1" action.
Accordingly, the first condition also does not work due to `$reply_markup`

This SDK used in my project: [click](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs)

How should i fix this?
ty <3

Comment: Just in case, I’ll clarify that the bot should respond to the user `Hello there!` and send him a menu with three buttons specified in `$keyboard`

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
$reply_markup = $telegram->replyKeyboardMarkup([ 'keyboard' => $keyboard, 'resize_keyboard' => true, 'one_time_keyboard' => false ]);
```

to:

```
$reply_markup = json_encode([ 'keyboard' => $keyboard, 'resize_keyboard' => true, 'one_time_keyboard' => false ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use reply markup buttons you should always encode them as a JSON format use `json_encode($reply_markup)` instead of using `$reply_markup`.